# Choice to Post to Facebook After Clicking Like Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I noticed at [9gag.com/fast](http://9gag.com/fast) that if you click the `Like` button, a small option opens up to share that link on the user's wall.

I believe this is not a default option because I have implemented the Like button on my site and it doesn't work that way.

How to get this functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create')` as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) with the JS SDK to catch the event when a user likes your page.

Comment: Thanks @Yan ... But can you like give the complete sort of the code or a link to any tutorial that does that. (am still a noob in this)

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to subscribe to the like event. The behavior you describe in that link is default. Go to the link generator here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ to play around with it. Any time you click on like a little comment box will popup.

Comment: It does work on linked FB developers page, but if I paste the generated code into my page, only like button works, but not the sharing functionality. Any hints ?

Comment: It works only if you use the SDK version [HTML5] and the [XFBML].